# Git push is set 'upstream' in conf, but want to use 'matching' occasionally

Tags: git, git-push

I recently switched to `upstream` for my `git push` configuration (meaning only the current branch will be pushed to its upstream counterpart), to avoid unexpected things being pushed. However, there are some times I'm sure I want to have the default `push` behaviour (being `matching`), and push all branched to their matching counterparts. How can I achieve that without changing my configuration ? I've seen `git push` can have an `--all` options, but it looks like it pushes all branches. As I cannot test it right now, I'm turning to you guys.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just do `git push origin branchname` or set an alias for that and keep doing that without changing any configuration? That way your `git push` will remain the normal default.

Comment: I could, but I'd like to avoid it. I believe `upstream` should be the default conf, and using shell aliases is just a workaround. As for typing the full name... It's just plain laziness. But I've been told it's a valid reason when you're a developper : )

Comment: Well, considering there's no way to achieve what I want the way I want, I went back to the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I'm new to GIT :)

Looking at git-push documentation (both on my local GIT and [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)) I found this:

```
git push origin : 
 Push "matching" branches to origin. See <refspec> in
 the OPTIONS section above for a description of "matching" branches.
```

I would say this is the command you were looking for.